# Split function NoMethodErrorException as I am looping through each element using Gherkin (Ruby) but last element is invalid

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I am getting "NoMethodErrorException"
" undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
"

the issue seems to be because of the last element that I am using , but I am not finding a way to ignore the last element in the feature file

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: @spickermann here it is : And evaluation of `@result[:response].split("/\n")` is stored in the :console_output_array clipboard
#Last element coming out as "," 
When I repeat the following steps for each :console_output in cb.console_output_array:
   """   And evaluation of `cb.console_output.split(":")[1].split("]")[0]` is stored in the :provider_status clipboard
   And evaluation of `cb.console_output.split("/\t")[1]` is stored in the :instance_state clipboard
   Then the expression should be true> cb.provider_status == cb.instance_state
   """ Then the step should succeed

Comment: so basically this is happening :consoleOutput = "'"

puts consoleOutput.split("/\t")[1].split("/") in step definition because of which it is giving exception

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reject the last element, then you may do something like this

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6]    
a.pop
p a
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Once the last element is rejected then you can iterate the array and can perform your operation

```
a.each do |val|
  p val
end
```

Comment: I cannot directly change the step_definitions , hence cannot use above solution